# How can I disable the Design-Mode in VisualStudio options

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

How can I use only the XAML-Code-View without Visual Studio **load** the Design-Mode?

I need every Time disable the designMode, i cant find this in my options...

[image]
<sub>(source: [biggle.de](http://www.biggle.de/allView2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In **vs2015** goto:

Tools > Options > Xaml Designer

Choose "Source View" for "Default Document view"

or you can disable it completely by unchecking "Enable XAML Designer"

In **vs2010** goto:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Miscellaneous

Under "Default View" Section

check Always open documents in full XAML view

Comment: This is especially relevant now that VS 2017 RC is out.  For me the #%$@ design mode would randomly pull me out of the XAML view.  They're doing something now that when you're editing the XAML, something triggers the designer to reload.  Being able to uncheck 'Enable XAML Designer' stops that BS dead in its tracks!

Comment: Thank you for this. Just an FYI for anyone else looking for this, the setting *Enable XAML Designer* still present and works in VS 2022 and 2019

Answer (score 22):

Right click .xml file in **"Source Explorer"**, select **"Open With"** and choose **"Source Code(Text) Editor"** as default.

Comment: For some reason Visual Studio keeps forgetting this setting and reverting to the Xaml editor.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2015, It can be also achieved by clicking the `collapse` icon then clicking the `XAML` icon, it will first show designer only then it will show the xaml code only and keep the designer collapsed just in case you need it.

**Click the collapse icon (The double arrows)**
[image: Click the collapse icon]

**Click the XAML icon (XAML with code sign)**
[image: Click the XAML icon]

**This is what it should look like after clicking the XAML icon**

[image: Click the xaml icon]

**Finally** you can `Save window layout` from the window menu, and use the layout  when you open your project next time.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2017, navigate to Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer.

Change the combobox labeled "Default document view" from "Split View" to "Source View".